# Not able to have all orientation for iPad

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

Hi guys i know this question might be asked before as well , so if u could point out right question to refer to that would be great .

Problem - in my info.plist i have only 2 orientation allowed i.e Portrait ,UpsideDown
and every viewController abides to above orientation .
But for one particular viewController i want whole 360 degree orientation .

this viewController is presented modally with style 
UIModelPresentationStyle.FullScreen

And to support all orientation in ViewController , 
i have overridden relevant delegate methods as well

ShouldAutorotate is returning -> Yes ,
PreferredOrientationForPresentation is returning ->  UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ;

GetSupportedInterfaceOrientation is returning -> UIINterfaceOrientationMask.all

When this ViewController loads i am getting landscapeLeft as expected , when i rotate the iPad, i get portrait mode as well , 
but now i am not able to return back to landscape mode anymore .

Any reason for that???

Answer (score 0):

> in my info.plist i have only 2 orientation allowed

Well, that's the problem. You're doing this wrong. The *Info.plist* should list *every* orientation that the app can *ever* have. Your top-level view controllers can then *limit* their own orientations.

Comment: Matt I respect your opinion but I can't change the project architecture just for the sake of one customer demand . I need to find a hack of some kind which would allow me to have all orientation for one spefic controller without messing with plist if I could

Comment: Sure, you can do that by changing what is returned by the app delegate's `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`. But it must still be a superset of anything returned by any of your view controllers. View controllers can only _limit_ it, they cannot _expand_ it.